# How to put breakpoint to a go method with gdb or delve

Tags: go, gdb, delve

I want to debug a go code. I want to put breakpoint on a method (belonging to a named type) in a imported package. I went through a lot of online materials where they only put breakpoints on a line number in file (eg:`breakpoint a.go:15`).

I have done a lot of debugging in 'C' where I put breakpoints on functions. Is this kind of debugging possible in go??

I have the following code in my main package.

`clientContext := sdk.Context(fabsdk.WithUser("Admin"), fabsdk.WithOrg("ordererorg"))`.

I want to put breakpoints to

1) function `WithUser()` which belongs to package `fabsdk` in file `github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/fabsdk/context.go`.
2) method `Context()` belonging to type `FabricSDK` in file `github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/fabsdk/fabsdk.go` in package `fabsdk`.

Is it possible to put breakpoints to method `WithUser()` and `context()` or Isbreakpoints only allowed at a line number in a file?? I could use either gdb or delve or any other debugger as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the version of `github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/fabsdk/context.go` that was used to build your Go binary — for example, in your `src` or `vendor` directory — then just open that file, find the [`WithUser`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/blob/46e0598989cd3b71a75badf03191af724c8a1210/pkg/fabsdk/context.go#L25) function, and put a breakpoint on its first line.

Comment: thank you vasily for the suggestion/answer. We need to mention the path of symbol in breakpoint eg: "b github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/fabsdk.WithUser"